# Unable to install Xcode due to OSX version conflict, but version is sufficient

Tags: macos, xcode, version

this is my first post on superuser though I hang out on Stackoverflow a fair amount.

*Disclaimer, I'm an OSX noob.*  Anyway, this one has me stumped.  When I go to the Apple Store and attempt to install Xcode version 4.5.2, I see this error:

> Xcode can't be installed on MacOSX because Mac OS X version 10.7.4 or later is required.

However, when I open a shell and do a `uname -a` I see:

> Darwin xxxx 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Looks to me like that says I'm running 10.8.0.  Just in case, I did manual check for software updates, there were a couple.  I installed them, rebooted, still seeing the same thing.

**EDIT** - Forgot to mention, I also tried downloading Xcode and installing from the `.dmg`, but saw the exact same error.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved.  `uname` reports the kernel version.  When selecting "About This Mac" under the Apple menu it reports that I'm actually running *OSX* version 10.6.8.  Sigh.